I am working on a Blazor Server App. How can I get all the roles a user has?
I am trying to get all roles a user has by using .Roles
my problem is that individualUser.Roles always returns null. I am VERY new to Blazor .net authentication, can somebody explain what am I missing? Thank you.
This is what I have tried:
private string GetRoleForUser(
    CoolAviationTrainingSolutions.Models.ApplicationUser individualUser)
{
    string roleslist = individualUser.Roles.ToString();
    return roleslist;
}


We need more context, what is individualUser and how do you retrieve it?
